# Arithmetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, pseudocode

I was going through some interview question and stumbled upon this question. p(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x^2 + ... + anx^n. What algorithm could you use to to compute the value of p(x) in O(N^2) ? I'm totally clueless about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Which value? Also I think you mean p(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x^2 + ... + anx^n.

Comment: Value of P(x) and yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @LeonardoCooper - Software Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in `O(N)` with direct evaluation or with [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). A useful chart for complexity of various operations and the methods involved can be found here:

[Computational complexity of mathematical operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

Horner's method is a serial procedure that optimizes "sub-expressions of form (A+ Bx) which be evaluated using a native multiply–accumulate instruction on some architectures". A more parallel version is [Estrin's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme).

Since you can compute the `p(x)` in `O(N)` time, apply this method `N` times to achieve `O(N^2)` (if that is really what you are after...).

Comment: @NickChris O(N^2) is a superset of O(N).

Comment: Maybe the interviewer assumed that `pow(X,N)` is implemented in O(N) time using iterated multiplication? In which case direct evaluation is O(N^2).

Comment: @Kevin Horner's method does not require the use of `pow`, so this still isn't an issue. It is possible that the interviewer wasn't aware of any other method than direct evaluation though!

Answer (score 1):

Since each term is independent and there are N terms, you must performs `O(N)` calculations of a polynomial term. Since the worst cast term is `(a_n)*(x^n)` and `x^n` can be computed in `O(N)` you have exactly `O(N^2)` time for the naive implementation of the algorithm.

There are tricks however to compute `x^n` in less than O(N) time so you could do even better: see [an implementation of pow()](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c). Also Hoener's method as described by other answers provides a fast implementation which is `O(N)` time and thus also `O(N^2)` time.